# Extracting the first word in a text file and then the corresponding words?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, text-files

I have recently found this code but have been struggling to work out how it works. "111.txt" is a text file with lines of lists where the first part of the list on each line is a solution and the corresponding words in that list are key words to do with that solution. I understand most of it apart from line 8 (`solutions[i[-1]] ...`). I have been looking up the differnt modules used but I still don't understand what that line does and how it works. I am quite new to using Python so I would really appreciate a simple explanation of this line if possible.

Thanks in advance!

```
questionbank = []
with open ('111.txt') as questions:
    for line in questions:
        questionbank.append(line.strip().split(','))

solutions = {}
for i in questionbank:
    solutions[i[-1]] = i[0:len(i)-1]

def phone_problem():
    n = 2
    while n <3:
        problem = input("Phone problem?")
        for d,v in solutions.items():
            if any(word in problem for word in v):
                print(d)
                n = 4
            else:
                continue

phone_problem()
```

Example of "112.txt":

```
put your phone is rice, wet, damp, water, puddle
replace you screen, screen, crack, smash, shatter...
```

UPDATE:
I have added in your code but it still does't output a solution. It just continues to run the while loop no matter what I type in as the problem. I'm really not sure why but it may be to do with when you defined solution.

```
import webbrowser,time
url = "https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNuLiL1vHRAhVjD8AKHdFEAiEQPAgD&gws_rd=cr&ei=zUiTWKKpF8P_UoSambgO#hl=en&q="
problem = input("What is the problem with you device?")
split = problem.split(" ")
keyList = []

def other():
        print("no solution")

questionbank = []


with open ('111.txt') as questions:
    for line in questions:
        questionbank.append(line.strip().split(','))
# the following line are probably the source of the problem(up to calling the phone_problem function)
solutions = {question[0]:question[1:] for question in questionbank}


def phone_problem():
    while True:
        for solution, key_words in solutions.items():
            if any(word in problem for word in key_words):
                print(solution)
                return 

phone_problem()
if keyList == []:
    with open("counter.txt", "r") as file:
        for lines in file:
                number = lines[0]
    file.close()
    text_file = open("help.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(str(int(number)+1))
    text_file.write("\n{}                      {}                              {}                                  {}                          {}".format(number,devType,brand,device,problem))
    text_file.close()
    other()
keyList = list(set(keyList))
for i in keyList:
    print("Solution:",i)
```

Comment: Please add sample input from 111.txt

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in the comments below...

```
solutions = {}
for i in questionbank:
    # i = ['put your phone is rice', 'wet', 'damp', 'water', 'puddle']
    # i[-1] means last thing in list = 'puddle'
    # i[0:len(i)-1] means everything in i except the last element
    #               which could be rewritten as i[:-1]
    solutions[i[-1]] = i[0:len(i)-1]
    # solutions['puddle'] = ['put your phone is rice', 'wet', 'damp', 'water']
```

I think that the code is buggy. Shouldn't the solution key be the first element of the line? The code would be better written as follows.

```
solutions = {question[0]:question[1:] for question in questionbank}

def phone_problem():
    while True:
        problem = input("Phone problem?")
        for solution, key_words in solutions.items():
            if any(word in problem for word in key_words):
                print(solution)
                return
```